# TwitterAPIExchange.php on US Server

Tags: php, twitter

I am building a tool for twitter monitoring, essentially pulling in the recent tweets by pages, and analysing them.

I'm coming up against a bit of a roadblock though, my code (below) works fine on my MAMP on my computer, but as soon as I put it on my WAMP server, which is hosted in the US by my company, it returns 'boolean false'

```
    <?php

    require_once('src/TwitterAPIExchange.php');

    $settings = array(
        'oauth_access_token' => "",
        'oauth_access_token_secret' => "",
        'consumer_key' => "",
        'consumer_secret' => ""
    );

    $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json';
    $getfield = '?screen_name=nike';
    $requestMethod = 'GET';
    $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);

    $response = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
    //$response = $twitter
                 ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                 ->performRequest();     

    var_dump($response);
    $decoded = json_decode($response,true);
    ?>
```

Response when I run on my mamp is the expected results, when I run on my WAMP on the US server, it returns 'boolean false'

Is it a firewall issue or something to that effect? Or am I missing something fundamental here?

Thanks!

Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find the other StackExchange post that asked this question, but the answer was found here: https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/issues/32a#issuecomment-24660844

> try re-adding CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false in the performRequest() method in TwitterAPIExchange.php

Comment: That works PERFECTLY. Incredible thanks so much. Quick question, how on earth would I know to do that!?

Comment: It took me about an hour of Googling and searching here before I found the answer. j7mbo is the author of the TwitterAPIExchange.php, so it makes sense that he would have the answer.

Comment: Well thanks so much! I couldn't for the life of me find the problem. Probably shoulda checked j7mbo's github really...